# Is it possible to have only two items in each row in a two column grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having some issues with aligning items that are in a two column grid. If you look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsF5D.png), you see that these items are not aligned properly. You will notice that 'Example 3' is not aligned with 'Example 4'. I think the issue is that since 'Example 2' does not have a description, 'Example 3' is occupying that empty space on 'Example 2'.

The behavior should such that, even if there is no description for any example, 'Example 1' should align with 'Example 2'(row 1). 'Example 3' should align with 'Example 4'(row 2). [It should be like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gShZ0.png)

I am not sure what is causing this mis-alignment. I am not sure if my bootstrap is wrong. I am using `Col-sm-6 Col-md-6` . Here is my code:

```
<div class="myTree">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            @if(link !=null)  // if link is there, then it shoud apply to image and title.
            {
            <a href="@link.URL" title="@link.LinkName" target="@link.TargetWindow">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="treeimagewithLink">
                        <img class="treeimage" alt="@image.GetAttributeValue("AlternateText")" title="@image.GetAttributeValue("AlternateText")" src="images/@image.Value" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="treeTitle">
                        <h3>@title</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="treeexcerpt">
                <p>@Html.Raw(Model.GetElementValue("description"))</p>
            </div>
            }
            else{ // if there is no link 
            <div class="imagewithnoLink">
                <img class="treeimage" alt="@image.GetAttributeValue("AlternateText")" title="@image.GetAttributeValue("AlternateText")" src="images/@image.Value" />
            </div>
            <div class="treeTitle">
                <h3>@title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="treeexcerpt">
                <p>@Html.Raw(Model.GetElementValue("description"))</p>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Im suggesting you to use [Tailwind Css](https://tailwindcss.com/) and check this cool awesome video [Tailwind Labs](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOe-8z68tgw9ioqVvYM4ddQ) If you are not required to use bootstrap. Its easier and more responsive

Comment: Both Example 1 and Example 2 should be placed inside the same `<div class="row"> ... </div>` and same for Example 4 and Example 3. This will make sure 1 and 2 stay at the same row while 3 and 4 stay at another row.

More info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Can you please post the rendered HTML instead of templating that makes it difficult to repro the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class `row` to `myTree`.

This will cause `myTree` to gain `display: flex`.

Edit: OK. It looks like you clearly have `float` on your `col-md-6`, which probably means you're using bootstrap v3, not v4. (Bootstrap v3 uses float instead of flexbox.)

Therefore I'd recommend adding some flexbox manually.

CSS:

```
.myTree{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.myTree>.col-md-6{
   flex:1 1 auto;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
    .myTree>.col-md-6{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to make it more global over your entire website, you can instead override bootstrap entirely, like this:

```
.row{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

[class*=col-]{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
    [class*=col-]:not([class*="col-xs"]){
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Edit 2: I've just realized your HTML might actually be the problem. Your final result should probably look something like this:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <div class="myTree col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="myTree col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="myTree col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="myTree col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

.myTree{
   flex:1 1 auto;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
    .myTree{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224965/discussion-on-answer-by-eliezer-berlin-is-it-possible-to-have-only-two-items-in).

Answer (score 0):

Changed `<div class="myTree">`    to  `<div class="row">`  then add `<div class="col-**">` in bottom `class="row"` after it add a `<div class="myTree">`

Comment: Sir, I am bit confused.  Can you show the structure if you don't mind?

Comment: I’m guess if you make a column for same width and height, need a row into bootstrap Css, And you want to sort example 1 to the left of example 2 and Example 3 to the left of example 4. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Odd item on the left side. Even item  on the right side. And only two items per row. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gShZ0.png